# 3D reconstruction from a wireframe sketch

Tags: 3d, 3d-reconstruction, sketching

I want to reconstruct the 3-D shape of an object based on a raw hand-drawn sketch. The sketch contains also the invisible lines of the object, and it is drawn on top of an already existing 3-D scene (of a city). I might be able to recover some 3-D points based on their coincidence with other objects from the city.

Reconstructed shapes do not need to be 100% precise, some inaccuracies are permitted, and they don't contain curves and curved surfaces, only plain polygons.

I have found this topic:

[generate 3d object from processing a 2d sketch on paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915057/generate-3d-object-from-processing-a-2d-sketch-on-paper)

but it seems that the problem there is not constrained at all, in contrast to my case. I also have read some papers, the newest one and most descriptive one is this one:
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.118.2577&rep=rep1&type=pdf

The paper implements an algorithm based on constraints (e.g. parallel lines, parallel faces, symmetry, minimal distances, etc.). But it has no available implementation...

I would like to implement a fast-and-dirty parallelized algorithm, but I don't seem to find any code to start from... I would appreciate any hint or link to an existing implementation. I know it is a hard problem, but I am sure it is not impossible to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution to this problem, although not exactly the one I'm looking for:

[Shape recognition and physics simulation](http://gamesalfresco.com/2009/10/16/ismar-2009-sketch-and-shape-recognition-preview-from-ben-gurion-university/)

This approach recognizes shapes out of **visible edges** only. The user does not have to draw the invisible edges. I would like to use the invisible edges too.

Unfortunately, I couldn't get access to the source code, even though they've given an e-mail for interest towards the source.